# obtainPermanentIDsForObjects doesn't make passed in object's IDs permanent immediately

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I've been wrestling with temporary core data objects within my iOS app for a fair few months now. I use UIManagedDocument which may or may not complicate things a little. The problem I have is when views are trying save URIs for objects during state encoding for restoration I hit problems whenever newly created objects have objectID's that are temporaryIDs.

Previously I'd tried to force save the UIManagedDocument with the following

```
NSError *saveError=nil;
BOOL bSuccess=[document.managedObjectContext save:&saveError];

[document updateChangeCount:UIDocumentChangeDone];
[document savePresentedItemChangesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *errorOrNil)
```

I thought this was helping fix the temporary objectIDs, it was definitely forcing the saving to store/disk (which shouldn't be necessary when using the more automated UIManagedDocument), but I since discovered that newly created object id's on the document.managedObjectContext were still left with temporary ObjectIDs even after this.

Last night I discovered that the following brute force addition done after the save has occurred in the savePresentedItemChangesWithCompletionHandler's completion handler block seemed to be able to fix up the temporary ObjectIDs that I was still experiencing.

```
[document.managedObjectContext reset];
```

This presumably discards the entire context and forces everything to be refreshed with the new permanent ids following the save having completed. I presume this would require at least some form of SQL db being reloaded from disk and so wasn't really an ideal solution.

Finally I discovered that there may be another solution, one that doesn't require brute force saving on the UIManagedDocument, and that's to instead do the following on any newly created NSManagedObject instead

```
NSError *obtainError=nil;
BOOL bObtainSuccess = [object.managedObjectContext obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:@[object] error:&obtainError];
```

I do think that this seems to do what's written on the tin. If I test for object's being temporary even just a second or so later then it seems to clear up and find ALL object's processed as permanent. However if I try to test whether they're permanent immediately after calling obtainPermanentIDsForObjects as follows

```
NSError *obtainError=nil;
BOOL bObtainSuccess = [object.managedObjectContext obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:@[object] error:&obtainError];
assert(![[object objectID] isTemporaryID]);
```

Then the assert fires, ie. the object still has a temporaryID even though the obtainPermanentIDsForObjects method returned YES, and left obtainError as nil.

This is all done on the main thread, without any context performBlock.. Given the configuration of UIManagedDocument though this should be correct I think.

Has anyone got any thoughts on this? For now hopefully it seems to be ok if i don't check immediately, almost like there's some threading to the operation, which does make me wonder if it should be done on some different thread...

Thanks for your time

Comment: I suspect `UIManagedDocument` is complicating things because of its nested MOCs. I wonder (don't know if it'll work) if you'd be better using `object.managedObjectContext.parentContext` to get the permanent IDs.

Comment: Thanks for the idea Tom. I thought I'd already tried this, and encountered errors about objects not being associated with contexts, perhaps that was what occurred with some of the earlier solutions i outlined in the original post.

I just tried obtaining permanent IDs from the objects.managedObjectContext.parentContext and whilst no errors occurred the assert still fired that the ids were temporary.

Thanks for the idea though!